# Can the methods in an Enum type change the state of the instances of an Enum?

Tags: java, enums

If Enums are an answer for getting rid of compile time constants , why did the language designers provide facility to let arbitrary methods and fields and implement arbitrary interfaces on Enums ? Those methods can never change the state of the Enum instances or can they ? If they are allowed to change the state , then the invariant of an Enum type ie some type that exports a few constants will break IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java enums are really just classes with some special treatment by the compiler and runtime. So yes, method calls on an enum instance can certainly change its state. I'm not sure what you mean with "then the invariant of an Enum type ie some type that exports a few constants will break".

Who says enums can only be a bunch of constants? The essence of an enum type is that you have a predefined fixed number of instances which you can refer to by name - and Java enums implement that. But why would a language not be allowed to have enums that are more powerful than that?

If you don't want the extra power, nobody forces you to use it. You can have Java enums without fields or methods, and they'll behave pretty much exactly like C enums.

Comment: I meant Enums are immutable and providing methods can alter this invariant as they can possibly change the state of the Enum.

Comment: @Geek: The number, names and identity of instances of an enum are immutable. That they can have mutable state does not change this. Where do you see a problem?

Comment: since the fields has to be final (and it is enforced by the compiler) , it doesn't matter. Otherwise immutability of the instances of enum won't hold . These fields just associate some data with the instances . they can never change the state of the instances per se.

Comment: @Geek: That's not true - the compiler will happily accept non-final fields in an enum. I have no idea where you got this idea that "enum instances must be immutable".

Comment: Isn't it pretty intuitive ? Enums by design are meant to represent constants and constants can't be mutable because they are plain constants .

Comment: @Geek: I think you're mistaking the implementation detail of how enums work in C for a fundamental design. Enums represent a type with a fixed, predefined set of instances. That has nothing to do with constants. C-style enums are actually a pretty limited and weak construct.

Comment: @Geek you can write your Enum as immutable and use that for constants (which is also how enum is used in most case) doesn't mean it is the only possibility or goal for enum.  And, even compiler constraint all fields to be final, it doesn't help.  Please be reminded that Java does not have const-pointer/const-ref equivalent of C/C++  ( const Foo * / const Foo & )

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Thanks to you and Adrian  for clearing up the confusion .

Answer (score 1):

Enums are compile-time constants, but their members aren't. It's usually not a good idea to change enum members at runtime, but it is possible. For this reason, you can't use an enum's members where compile-time constants are called for (e.g. in annotation parameters).

Hardly anything in Java is really a constant when you go try hard to mess things up. E.g. a String constant contains a char array. Arrays are not immutable. Here's an example of the mess you can make using inlined String constants:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Field valueField = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
    valueField.setAccessible(true);
    System.arraycopy("frog".toCharArray(), 0,
        (char[]) valueField.get(Boolean.TRUE.toString()), 0, 4);
    System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("frog")); // true
    System.out.println(Boolean.parseBoolean("true")); // false
}
```

So, Java constants in most cases are just constants as long as your application is well-behaved.

Answer (score 0):

> why did the language designers provide facility to let arbitrary methods and fields and implement arbitrary interfaces on Enums

Reasons are to allow replacing switch-statements with polymorphism and generally make programs more Object Oriented by allowing to define methods on the data.

Search for "type-safe enum pattern". Java Enums are an implementation of this design pattern on language level.